How to resolve "Removed N rows containing non-finite values" warning when performing ggpubr::stat_compare_means()?
I am trying to use ggpubr::stat_compare_means() to display significance between 2 groups of a ggplot2 geom_bar() plot and no matter what arguments I alter within ggpubr::stat_compare_means(), I receive:
Warning message: Removed 7 rows containing non-finite values (stat_signif()). 
with no change to my plot whatsoever.
I have successfully used the same function to display significance bars above groups in a previous ggplot2 object, so I am unsure what I am doing wrong this time round.
The data I am using to construct the plot:
    data.frame(Genotype = c("TH-Rab10-UASxRILPL-RNAi","THGxEV","THGxRILPL-RNAi","THGxRab10-RNAi","THGxRab10-UAS","THxEV","THxRILPL-RNAi","THxRab10-RNAi","THxRab10-UAS"),
               n = c(15L, 26L, 8L, 25L, 17L, 47L, 17L, 18L, 35L),
                LengthQ1 = c(18.280688,
                             11.82689575,15.90614625,13.849324,13.347111,15.859345,
                             13.731412,14.47231875,15.0489065),
            LengthMedian = c(20.929077,
                             14.115312,17.9934025,15.063749,14.467557,18.472372,
                             15.476185,15.8676385,16.600054),
                LengthQ3 = c(22.701097,
                             20.47221725,18.84823975,17.26818,15.708771,21.061999,
                             17.499193,17.2543175,19.2809775),
               LengthIQR = c(4.420409,8.6453215,
                             2.9420935,3.418856,2.36166,5.202654,3.767781,
                             2.78199875,4.232071),
              DistanceQ1 = c(15.2804085,
                             8.5671065,10.739529,7.99746,7.9431825,13.051536,
                             8.269126,10.6521055,10.439186),
          DistanceMedian = c(19.198656,
                             10.5478945,14.1065015,8.792743,9.3206415,15.368998,
                             9.503684,11.5414735,12.549259),
              DistanceQ3 = c(19.920061,
                             14.2409875,14.72976275,11.606169,11.1989975,17.441512,
                             12.348101,14.69524325,16.0352985),
             DistanceIQR = c(4.6396525,5.673881,
                             3.99023375,3.608709,3.255815,4.389976,
                             4.078975,4.04313775,5.5961125),
              AvgSpeedQ1 = c(0.60935627,
                             0.39422985,0.53020487,0.46164414,0.44490367,
                             0.528644815,0.45771372,0.482410645,0.50163022),
          AvgSpeedMedian = c(0.6976359,
                             0.47051041,0.59978007,0.50212497,0.4822519,0.6157458,
                             0.51587284,0.52892127,0.55333513),
              AvgSpeedQ3 = c(0.75670322,
                             0.6824073,0.628274675,0.57560605,0.52362573,
                             0.702066625,0.58330643,0.57514394,0.64269925),
             AvgSpeedIQR = c(0.14734695,
                             0.28817745,0.0980698050000001,0.11396191,0.07872206,
                             0.17342181,0.12559271,0.092733295,0.14106903),
              MaxSpeedQ1 = c(2.1295190602541,
                             1.55741482973099,1.76144074648619,1.62141680717468,
                             1.65458209812641,1.62481656298041,
                             1.79684981703758,1.68653343804181,1.57950421795249),
          MaxSpeedMedian = c(2.31243431568146,
                             2.40550730377436,1.94318845868111,1.78365088999271,
                             1.87738806009293,1.88665978610516,
                             2.5744204223156,1.93664135411382,1.84467315673828),
              MaxSpeedQ3 = c(2.52435296773911,
                             4.38153522089124,2.06372201442719,2.02216498553753,
                             2.63166323304176,2.23176073282957,
                             3.09925630688667,2.14401628822088,2.34918303787708),
             MaxSpeedIQR = c(0.394833907485008,
                             2.82412039116025,0.302281267940998,
                             0.400748178362846,0.977081134915352,0.606944169849157,
                             1.30240648984909,0.457482850179076,0.769678819924593),
               AvgAreaQ1 = c(4.43887,
                             2.796593625,3.2405515,2.8232188,3.0771978,2.960016,
                             3.085381,2.960534225,2.8692408),
           AvgAreaMedian = c(4.5562806,3.06985,
                             3.4835652,3.0170968,3.1992326,3.1527348,
                             3.6117566,3.22332025,3.1957788),
               AvgAreaQ3 = c(4.920249,
                             3.299686975,3.704223525,3.2930808,3.3325727,3.2572896,
                             3.7764688,3.57171335,3.52520665),
              AvgAreaIQR = c(0.481379,
                             0.50309335,0.463672025,0.469862,0.2553749,0.2972736,
                             0.6910878,0.611179125,0.65596585),
                  BLPSQ1 = c(0.108832845,
                             0.0836447675,0.1028181325,0.09795997,0.08759048,
                             0.117704612,0.092220485,0.09742653,0.102725945),
              BLPSMedian = c(0.13211587,
                             0.101494045,0.110076575,0.10992522,0.09487153,
                             0.13728157,0.10149567,0.110070417,0.12031361),
                  BLPSQ3 = c(0.141670825,
                             0.1547064675,0.12659264,0.11499335,0.104149856,
                             0.15064992,0.11222159,0.1240795725,0.134860155),
                 BLPSIQR = c(0.03283798,
                             0.0710617,0.0237745075,0.01703338,0.016559376,
                             0.032945308,0.020001105,0.0266530425,0.03213421),
                 BendsQ1 = c(0, 0, 2.375, 0.5, 2.5, 0, 1, 1.125, 0.5),
             BendsMedian = c(0, 1, 3.75, 1.5, 3, 0.5, 2, 1.75, 1.5),
                 BendsQ3 = c(1.75, 2, 6.625, 4.5, 5.5, 2.25, 3, 4.125, 4.5),
                BendsIQR = c(1.75, 2, 4.25, 4, 3, 2.25, 2, 3, 4),
                  BBPSQ1 = c(0,0,
                             0.0791666666666667,0.0166666666666667,0.0833333333333333,0,
                             0.0333333333333333,0.0375,0.0166666666666667),
              BBPSMedian = c(0,
                             0.0333333333333333,0.125,0.05,0.1,0.0166666666666667,
                             0.0666666666666667,0.0583333333333333,0.05),
                  BBPSQ3 = c(0.0583333333333333,
                             0.0666666666666667,0.220833333333333,0.15,
                             0.183333333333333,0.075,0.1,0.1375,0.15),
                 BBPSIQR = c(0.0583333333333333,
                             0.0666666666666667,0.141666666666667,
                             0.133333333333333,0.1,0.075,0.0666666666666667,0.1,
                             0.133333333333333),
                PausesQ1 = c(0.5, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
            PausesMedian = c(1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 2),
                PausesQ3 = c(2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2.5, 2, 2, 2),
               PausesIQR = c(1.5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2.5, 1, 1, 1),
            TimeActiveQ1 = c(23, 20, 25.75, 23, 21, 26.5, 20, 22.5, 21),
        TimeActiveMedian = c(26, 22, 30, 26, 26, 29, 24, 26.5, 24),
            TimeActiveQ3 = c(29, 24, 30, 30, 28, 30, 27, 28.75, 26),
           TimeActiveIQR = c(6, 4, 4.25, 7, 7, 3.5, 7, 6.25, 5),
      ContractionPowerQ1 = c(0.19970702809376,
                             0.193385523194331,0.160030144839136,
                             0.165044324573552,0.152014788511409,0.156086728604612,
                             0.220784994750454,0.163324281827173,0.16728595717427),
  ContractionPowerMedian = c(0.210281223405833,
                             0.208503605813651,0.162723068054026,
                             0.183002440379377,0.159309971585162,0.170786895829701,
                             0.247766953494411,0.188511139238084,0.178650522602126),
      ContractionPowerQ3 = c(0.224062166362874,
                             0.2478395610311,0.166376678600983,
                             0.221537421939879,0.181781761026601,0.189996554582442,
                             0.286135150365519,0.205434286597455,0.200339346048616),
     ContractionPowerIQR = c(0.0243551382691142,
                             0.0544540378367694,0.00634653376184691,
                             0.0564930973663275,0.029766972515192,0.0339098259778297,
                             0.0653501556150653,0.0421100047702824,
                             0.0330533888743458),
      AvgPauseDurationQ1 = c(1,2.27083333333333,
                             0,0,1.66666666666667,0,2,1.25,2),
  AvgPauseDurationMedian = c(2,2.70833333333333,
                             0,2.33333333333333,3,1,4,2.33333333333333,4),
      AvgPauseDurationQ3 = c(4.5,4,2.125,3.5,
                             4,1.66666666666667,5.5,3,5.5),
     AvgPauseDurationIQR = c(3.5,
                             1.72916666666667,2.125,3.5,2.33333333333333,1.66666666666667,
                             3.5,1.75,3.5),
        ContractionsMean = c(21.1333333333333,
                             16.2307692307692,23.375,16.84,18.4117647058824,
                             22.0425531914894,14.0588235294118,18.4444444444444,
                             19.4571428571429),
          ContractionsSD = c(5.99841248839661,
                             6.00871162435138,4.24053568044685,5.77840808527747,
                             3.5188567662206,3.91739402513918,3.682230781661,
                             4.25955289316534,6.44133187334118),
          ContractionsSE = c(1.54878344474951,
                             1.17840530092767,1.49925576775374,1.15568161705549,
                             0.853448125208642,0.571410646170829,
                             0.893072144158175,1.00398624519333,1.08878380777454)
)


Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.1.0

The code I am using to construct the plot:

parametric <- "Contractions"

cdata <- summary %>% 
  select(Genotype, all_of(contains(parametric))) %>% 
  subset(Genotype %in% c("THxEV", "THGxEV"))

for(i in 1:length(parametric)) {
  c <- ggplot(data=cdata, aes(x=Genotype, 
                              y=.data[[paste0(parametric[i], "Mean")]], 
                              fill=Genotype)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", width=0.6) +
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("THxEV", "THGxEV"), 
                     labels = c("TH-Gal4/+", "TH-Gal4-Lrrk2-G2019S/+")) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(df[[parametric[i]]])), 
                       expand=c(0,0)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightgrey", "white")) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1), 
          legend.position = "none",
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          text = element_text(size = 14, family="serif")) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(
      ymin=.data[[paste0(parametric[i], "Mean")]]-.data[[paste0(parametric[i], "SE")]],
      ymax=.data[[paste0(parametric[i], "Mean")]]+.data[[paste0(parametric[i], "SE")]]),
      width=0.2, linewidth=0.7) + 
    labs(y="Mean", title="Contractions")
  
  my_comparisons = list(c("THxEV", "THGxEV"))
  
  stars_list <- list(cutpoints = c(0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, Inf), 
                     symbols = c("****", "***", "**", "*", "ns"))
  
  c <- c + stat_compare_means(data=summary, aes(group=Genotype), 
                              comparisons=my_comparisons, method="t.test", 
                              method.args=c(var.equal=TRUE),
                              size=5,
                              symnum.args = stars_list, 
                              na.rm=TRUE)
  

 figurePath <- "/Volumes/PROJECT/Research-Compendium/figures/"
  ggsave(filename=paste0(figurePath,
                        "c",i,"_",parametric[i],".png"), plot = c)
  assign(paste0("c",i),c)
  # Remove base figure object from environment 
  rm(c)
}

Created on 2024-04-11 with reprex v2.1.0
I have been at this for hours, and after reading anything and everything I can find related to non-finite value errors and ggpubr::stat_compare_means() I've come to a complete loss, so I would very much appreciate some assistance!

I am not sure if you can do it using ggpubr::stat_compare_means() with your current data. Alternatively, you could try to calculate all p values first, and use stat_pvalue_manual()

What's df[[ parametric[i] ]] inside scale_y_continuous?
